# Redirect my old WordPress to a new website outside of WordPress?

Tags: redirects, wordpress, 301-redirect

I had an old WordPress website (`example.fr`, paid domain) and a friend made me a better website hosted outside of WordPress (has nothing to do with WordPress) and I would just like to redirect all my traffic from `example.fr` to my new website at `example.com`. How can I do this?

I looked at this: https://en.support.wordpress.com/site-redirect/
but I don't understand why would I have to pay? This is a bit confusing (I'm rather new to this whole website stuff).

Comment: You still have the old (paid) domain presumably? Where is that registered?
 (Aside: Why did you get a new domain?) "I don't understand why would I have to pay?" - If you have you're own domain (which you appear to have) then you don't really need to, as you should be able to point that domain anywhere you like. AFAIK, that redirection service is really if you have a domain of the form `example.wordpress.com`.

Comment: Just to add... does your new site have the same URL structure as the old (WordPress) site? Or do you have a mapping of old to new URLs ready?

Comment: I do still have the old one. It is in wordpress. The new one is hosted at ovh.com. The reason we changed websites is we were very unhappy with the webdeveloppers we paid to make our wordpress website (the website does not look like what we wanted) so, in just a weekend, a friend made us another website and exactly as we wanted it. Now I want people that go to the old_site.fr to be redirected to new_site.com. The URL's are not the same, as the organization is different.  All I need is that when a user goes to old_site.fr/bla they are automatically redirected to new_site.com. Thx for your help!

Comment: Please use the names set aside specifically for documentation instead of some made up, especially when yours are not valid hostnames. So `www.example.com`, `www.example.net`,  `www.example.org` or anything under `.example`. Thank you in advance.

Comment: (I wasn't actually asking why you "changed websites", but why you changed domains?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...but I don't understand why would I have to pay?

That redirect service is really for when you want to redirect from a wordpress.com subdomain, eg. `example.wordpress.com`. And this also redirects to the same URL-path, which does not appear to be what you require (although you could potentially "fix" that with an undesirable second redirect at your new host). The fact that this costs money (apart from being sensible from a business model point of view) goes a long way to deter spammers.

If you had a paid domain at your old WordPress.com site (which I'm assuming was registered through WordPress themselves?) and you still have this domain (which you say you do) then there are other (possibly free) options available:

- [Set an `A` record in the DNS](https://en.support.wordpress.com/move-domain/setting-custom-a-records/) at your current registrar (ie. WordPress) that points to the new website.
- [Change the `NS` (NAMESERVER) records to point to your new host](https://en.support.wordpress.com/move-domain/change-name-servers/). This instructs your new host to control the master DNS records of this domain (if this is a service they offer).
- [Transfer this domain away to another registrar](https://en.support.wordpress.com/move-domain/transfer-domain-registration/) and either set an `A` record or change the `NS` records (as above). Perhaps to the same registrar where your new domain is registered?

You will need to configure your new host to accept requests at the old domain (eg. a new VirtualHost if you have server access or an AddOn or Alias domain in something like cPanel). Some hosting accounts are single domain accounts, so this *might* be a paid-for extra.

As you may realise from doing this: you didn't need a new domain (unless that was what you wanted). Since you now have the old and new domains pointing to the new site.

You can now create a redirect (if required) from the old to new domain in order to canonicalise the domain. This should not cost you anything at the new host (apart from developer costs).

Comment: Thanks. Well this is overcomplicated to be honest... Maybe I could just delete the old wordpress and just keep the new website. Maybe that's the simplest for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is SEO a concern? Or is it just to get the user to the new domain? Your friend that made the new site "in a weekend" sounds a bit of a _whizz_; can they not help?

Comment: No SEO concern. He said he is not familiar with these things. He is like me, a programmer that out of curiousity knows html, css, Javascript, so he can do static websites but neither of us really knows about all these putting websites live kind of thing